# Tag synonym request: chromedriver -> selenium-chromedriver

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

[chromedriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chromedriver) and [selenium-chromedriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selenium-chromedriver) are about the same topic. Their wikis are about identical as well.

Comment: I see that [tag:selenium-chromedriver] is a proposed synonym of [tag:chromedriver]. Since we have [tag:selenium-firefoxdriver], I propose we make [tag:selenium-chromedriver] the main tag.